# Accessing list-of-lists returned from tcl procedure

Tags: tcl

I have a procedure that returns a list of lists. I can't figure out how to access the inner lists without splitting them first. I'm sure there must be a cleaner way.

For example, this:

```
proc return_l_of_l {} {
  set x {a b c}
  set y {d e f}
  return [list [list $x] [list $y]]
}
set l [return_l_of_l]
set x_list [lindex $l 0]
set y_list [lindex $l 1]

foreach x $x_list { puts $x }
foreach y $y_list { puts $y }
```

outputs:

```
a b c
d e f
```

not:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Comment: When printing the inner elements of the list of lists, it's better to use something like `foreach a [concat {*}$l] {puts $a}`. `concat {*}$l` creates a flat list containing the inner elements, which means it doesn't matter how many lists there are in the outer list: you can still print them with one `foreach` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
return [list [list $x] [list $y]]
```

Since `x` and `y` already hold lists, it makes a list of lists of lists. You should instead do:

```
return [list $x $y]
```

or possibly:

```
return [list [list {*}$x] [list {*}$y]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
proc return_l_of_l {} {
  set x {a b c}
  set y {d e f}
  return [list [list $x] [list $y]]
}
```

returns a list of two lists each consisting of a single element — `a b c` and `d e f`. That's because `{a b c}` and `{d e f}` are already constructs which can be interpreted as lists.

Supposedly you'd just need

```
return [list $x $y]
```